# How can I scrape a div that has images with Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a div that goes like this

```
<div class="main">
     <span class="something">TEXT</span>
     <span class="something">TEXT</span>
     <span class="something">TEXT</span>
     <span class="something">[HERE GOES AN IMAGE]</span>
     <span class="something">TEXT</span>
     <span class="something">TEXT</span>
     <span class="something">[HERE GOES AN IMAGE]</span>
     <span class="something">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

I am able to print the content of this div using `.text`, however, how can I extract the text of the div with the images?

Comment: What do you mean ? You see text on the image ?

Comment: It's just a regular text with image tags on the middle. More specifically: https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes/48a301a4-f7

Comment: Please show a specific example. What you've shown makes no sense because you can't have an image in the *span* element in the way that your sample implies. Most likely there be an *href* attribute that gives the location of the image

Comment: This seems like more of a image processing task than a web scrapping

Comment: This is an example of an element I will need to extract https://pastebin.com/YgMBaTBY I am able to extract the element's text using `.text` (In this case, is literally the letter A). However, letter A is followed by an image that I also need to scrape. How can I collect both image and text (instead of only the text)?